Get tfs changeset based on build in .NET 8
I have a .NET 8 web application that displays the product's version to the user.
Within the csproj file i have the following setting among others:
<PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.0.0.1</VersionPrefix>
</PropertyGroup>

Instead of manually updating the build value 1.0.0.[1] from time to time I would like this value to be updated automatically with the current build's changeset.
This could be done either when checking in code or when publishing/building. Either works for me.
For example if I published changeset 1423 I would expect the version to be 1.0.0.1423.
I have seen a couple posts but they all mention getting the latest TFS changeset rather than the current build changeset which would create an issue if I were to publish an older build.
I am not sure if this is even possible but I will gladly listen to suggestions.

In pipelines,  you can use the predefined variable "Build.SourceVersion" to get the changeset which the current build is running for.

For your case, you can set a pipeline variable 'VerPrefix' and set it value as '1.0.0.$(Build.SourceVersion)'.

When evaluating the pipeline variable 'VerPrefix', the expression '$(Build.SourceVersion)' will be parsed as the actual changeset. For example, when the changeset is '77', the value of 'VerPrefix' will be evaluated as '1.0.0.77'.
In the pipeline, you can use the .NET Core task to run the 'dotnet build' or 'dotnet publish' command for the .csproj file of your .NET 8 web app, and add the argument '-p:VersionPrefix=$(VerPrefix)' to the command. This argument will use the value of 'VerPrefix' to override the original value '1.0.0.1' when building the web app.



